# Upgrade Spring Boot 2.0.8 to 2.1.2 - Failed to load ApplicationContext in tests

Tags: spring, java-11

When upgrading spring from 2.0.8 to 2.1.2 (using JDK 8) the application starts and runs fine but tests fail due to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

I am using an abstract class which some tests do extend.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractTestkonfiguration {

  @TestConfiguration
  static class TestEnvironmentConfiguration {
    @Component
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:my-test.properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
    public static class MyTestProperties extends EnvironmentalProperties {
    }
  }

}
```

The class EnvironmentalProperties is a class for type-safe configuration properties ([Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties))

Before the upgrade that worked and a class of EnvironmentalProperties was provided but now I am getting a

```
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.abc.EnvironmentalProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 90 more
```

Could it be related to a change in Nested Configuration Class Detection ([Upgrading to Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x))? If so, how can I configure a bean of EnvironmentalProperties only for tests?

**Update:** Even if used as follows it doesn't work (same result).

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractTestkonfiguration {

  @Configuration
  public static class TestEnvironmentConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyTestProperties environmentalProperties(){
        return new EnvironmentalProperties() {
            // manual creation of an instance
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes that you have to make.

- You haven't enabled the configuration properties via `@EnableConfigurationProperties`
- The property source needs to be injected at test class
- Remove `@Component` annotation

Here is a working example;

`src/test/resources/my-test.properties`

```
my.server.name=foo
my.server=test
```

And

`src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
my.name=production
```

The production configuration.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class EnvironmentalProperties {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(value = {"classpath:my-test.properties", "classpath:application.properties"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AbstractTestkonfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private MyTestProperties myTestProperties;


    @TestConfiguration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyTestProperties.class)
    public static class TestEnvironmentConfiguration {
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
        public static class MyTestProperties  extends EnvironmentalProperties {
            private String server;

            public String getServer() {
                return server;
            }

            public void setServer(final String server) {
                this.server = server;
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void check_configuration () {
        Assert.assertEquals(myTestProperties.getServer(), "test");
        Assert.assertEquals(myTestProperties.getName(), "production");
    }
```

This works on Java 11 & spring-boot 2.1.2.RELEASE. Please note, this is only an example. You will have to adapt it to your project properly.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I made the following changes compared to the first example in my post: a) added `@TestPropertySource(value = {"classpath:my-test.properties"})` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties(AbstractTestkonfiguration.TestEnvironmentConfiguration.MyTestProperties.class)` at class level. 2) I removed  `@Component` and `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:my-test.properties")` at the configuration properties class. It didn't work with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` at the level of class `TestEnvironmentConfiguration`, though.

Comment: Glad that helped. That's correct `@EnableConfigurationProperties` should be at `TestEnvironmentConfiguration`. I alluded to `@TestPropertySource` on the test class btw.